# Delete all file/directories from each subfolder windows shell

Tags: windows, subdirectory

I have a question, I have the following paths:

```
C:\Vendita\folder1\files and subfolders
C:\Vendita\folder3\files and subfolders
C:\Vendita\folder3\files and subfolders
```

I want to delete (using win shell commands), for each subfolder (C:\Vendita\folder1,C:\Vendita\folder2,C:\Vendita\folder2...) all files and subfolders, but keeping folder1, folder2 ecc...

I try this:

```
for %D in (C:\Vendita\) do del *.* /s /q
```

but it deletes all files and keeps all subfolders.

Can you explain me what is wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `rmdir`? Your command only removes files with a certain filename.